# how to define custome distance function for string in elki?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, distance, elki

I'm using elki 0.7 to clustering tweets ( text ,date , author, ...).

in first step I'd like to cluster text of tweets.

I wrote a simple distance function and in the future I want to customized it.

```
public class Distance extends AbstractPrimitiveDistanceFunction<String> {
@Override
    public double distance(String str1, String str2) {
        int row1 = rowNumber.get(str1),
                row2 = rowNumber.get(str2);
        return 1 - similarity[row1][row2];
}
@Override
    public SimpleTypeInformation<? super String> getInputTypeRestriction() {
       return VectorFieldTypeInformation.typeRequest(String.class, 2, 2);
    }

}
```

similarity is an array that calculated normalized similarity of tweets (using tf-idf).
now I want to run clustering but SimpleTypeInformation function has an error.

```
The type of <V>typeRequest(Class<? super V>,int,int) is erroneous
   where V is a type-variable:
    V extends FeatureVector<?> declared in method <V>typeRequest(Class<? super V>,int,int)

incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
inferred: String
    upper bound(s): String,FeatureVector<?>
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You probably don't have a *vector field*, but a single string?

Comment: See https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/elki-core-distance/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/distance/distancefunction/strings/LevenshteinDistanceFunction.java for a string distance function.

Answer (score 3):

https://elki-project.github.io/dev/typeinformation

The type information is necessary for automatic type matching.

`VectorFieldTypeInformation` is used *only* for *vector fields*. Right now, you are claiming that your String is a 2 dimensional vector field, and that is supposed to give a compile error.

Your data are Strings, not a vector field of Strings; so you need to choose the appropriate subclass of TypeInformation for simple objects: `SimpleTypeInformation<String>` is what you want.

Your code uses a precomputed distance matrix. There are classes in ELKI for this, that are better optimized for this use case.

Comment: What classes are in ELKI for precomputed distance matrix?

Comment: See the howto for a starter: https://elki-project.github.io/howto/precomputed_distances

Comment: Yeah I read that, but I can't used it in java or ElkiMiniGUI. do you have any example?

Comment: I don't have a manual invocation example at hand - I avoid using full distance matrixes whenever possible. But you have the source, you can modify it as needed.